# How to pass Connection String from .NetCore to EF Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Overview:
I have two projects, one ASP.NetCore Web API and one EF 6.1 Class Library. The class library contains manager classes that interact with my database and return objects.

I followed this tutorial for dependency injection, but it does not address the scenario in my project where EF is in a separate class library and interaction takes place via manager classes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6

I got things working in the following way (but I am not happy because I don't want to overload the connection string):

```
    public class AccountManager
    {
        private static string ConnectionString = LibDataEntities.ConnectionString;

        public static AccountDC AuthenticateAccount(string EmailAddress, string Password)
        {
            LibData.Model.AccountDC account = null; 

            using (var db = new LibDataEntities(ConnectionString))
            {
                var qry = (from accounts in db.Accounts
                           where accounts.IsAdmin == true
                           && accounts.Active == true
                           && accounts.Email == EmailAddress
                           && accounts.Password == Password
                           select new LibData.Model.AccountDC
                           {
                               Active = accounts.Active,
                               Email = accounts.Email,
                               FirstName = accounts.FirstName,
                               Id = accounts.Id,
                               IsAdmin = accounts.IsAdmin,
                               IsSuperAdmin = accounts.IsSuperAdmin,
                               LastName = accounts.LastName,
                               LibraryId = accounts.LibraryId,
                               Password = accounts.Password
                           }).FirstOrDefault();

                if (qry != null)
                {
                    account = new LibData.Model.AccountDC();
                    account = qry;
                }
            }

            return account;
        }
}


   public partial class LibDataEntities
   {
      public static string ConnectionString;

      public LibDataEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
      {
      }
   }

  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {            
     // Set connection string in Manager Project
     LibData.Manager.Entities.LibDataEntities.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibDataEntities");

  }
```

Is it possible to interact with the class library managers WITHOUT having to overload the connection string (such as the example below)?

```
using (var db = new LibDataEntities())
```

FWIW: the reason I do not want to overload the connection string is because this class library is used by a non-asp.netcore application where the Web.Config already contains the connecting string.

Here is some new code I am trying without success (as indicated in one of my replies below:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMvcGrid();

        services.AddScoped(_ => new AccountManager());
        services.AddScoped<LibDataEntities>(_ => new LibDataEntities(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibDataEntities")));

    }

    private readonly AccountManager _am;
    public HomeController(AccountManager am)
    {
        _am = am;
    }
```

From the controller:

```
LibData.Model.AccountDC account = _am.AuthenticateAccount(lvm.Email, lvm.Password);
```

Comment: I think that if you want to follow the "Microsoft Style". AccountManager should not have static methods, and receive a LibDataEntities in the constructor and then setup the AccountManager and LibDataEntities in the DI

Comment: Instead of setting the connection string field you have, can you not inject the connection string into the Account Manager? Otherwise follow what kblok has said and inject your context into your `AccountManager`. If I were doing this and wanted to keep separation, I'd create a Database class which would use the context, and then inject an instance of that class into the `AccountManager` and every other Repository or Service you have.

Comment: The tutorial I followed (link in post above) was the first time I used DI. I was successful, but I was not able to figure out how to call my static methods in the AccountManager with the connection string injected.

ColinM, could you show me some code or point me to a good tutorial where I could research this a bit more? I like the idea of a Database class and keeping separation.

Comment: kblok, thank you for the feedback. I am so comfortable using static classes in the way I described... but am willing to attempt to follow the "Microsoft Style" -- as long as I can keep my separation of concerns. Again, this class library is used by more than one project and each project is of a different type/technology. Can  you give me an example of how to DI the AccountManager and LibDataEntities?

Comment: So, I attempted to DI the AccountManager. getting this error message : "No connection string named 'LibDataEntities' could be found in the application config file."  I will try to add some new code in the original post that corresponds to this reply.

Comment: @kblok That's not "Microsoft style". That's just basic Dependency Injection  pattern.

Comment: Of course @mason

Comment: @JasonSmith so you're close, Are you sure that you have the connstring named "LibDataEntities"?

Comment: Why not treat the connection string as an env variable?

Comment: The whole point of having Dependency Injection in place is **not to call `new MyClass()`**

Comment: @kblok that's the issue. in an asp.net core web application or web api the connection string for an entity is not picked up via the web.config / app.config / or appsettings.json. I cant seem to get that connection string 'regististered' to the db context in the EF class library.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud I do not have experience with Environment Variables. Can you give me an example of what that might look like?

Comment: I added the connection string to app.config in the ASP.Net Core application and the connection string was available to the EF Class Library. In other words, it's working without error.

Is this cheating? I feel like it's cheating.

Comment: @JasonSmith Why do you think its cheating. Storing connection strings in app.config is a common practice.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud I was only half joking. I guess I assumed that the app.config did not support connection strings in a .net core application. I mean... any tutorials I found online do not instruct to place the connection string in the app.config -- they instruct to place the connection string in the appsettings.json... then through DI, write your linq queries against the EF context.

Comment: @JasonSmith Yes in .net core the recommended practice is through appsettings.json or environment variables.